# How to change first coming scene in cocos2d-iphone, when user opens it second time?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a game using cocos2d. I have an introduction sprite( half-transparent,with pointers and explanations). After that some easy challenges follow, so that user can figure out how to play.

It doesn't make any sense to show introduction and easy things, when user plays game second time. So, I'd like to show a different one scene ,when user opens it not the first time.
How to implement a similar functionality?

Comment: I think an easy thing to do would be to save a flag in the NSUserDefaults after the tutorial finishes and then just check if it is already set in subsequent launches.

Comment: you are right @uchamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to add a custom plist to your app. plists are xml documents that can be used to save various types of information (scores, game progress, and in your case a 'tutorial has been played' flag)

Take a look at [this document](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html) for more information on how you can implement them in your app

Answer (score 0):

Posted this as a comment earlier.

I think an easier approach would be to save a flag in the NSUserDefaults after the tutorial finishes and then just check if it is already set in subsequent launches.